# How to set custom version of jdk in maven?

Tags: java, xml, windows, maven, netbeans

I am new in Maven.

I work in Windows and when I try to do the next instructions `mvn clean install` in folder with pom.xml file it throw me errors like this:

```
CLASS_NAME.java error: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
[ERROR] (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
```

As I can understand from the message it occurs because maven use jdk version 1.5 (Actually I even didn't install it). In maven settings folder I found toolchains.xml file. If I understood right, it is possible to set custom version of jdk for user using this file. So I add this code to my pom.xml file

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-toolchains-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <toolchains>
            <jdk>
                <version>[1.8]</version>
            </jdk>
        </toolchains>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>toolchain</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

and this to toolchains.xml

```
<toolchain>
    <type>jdk</type>
    <provides>
        <version>1.8</version>
        <vendor>sun</vendor>
    </provides>
    <configuration>
        <jdkHome>C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_45</jdkHome>
    </configuration>
</toolchain>
```

If somebody know can you tell me how to fix this? I will appreciate any help, idea or explanation.

P.S. JAVA_HOME is C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try configuring the `maven-compiler-plugin` instead of the `maven-toolchains-plugin` in your `pom.xml`.

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    [...]
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

[Source](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html)

Comment: Thaks a lot. This decision is working for me very good. Maybe you know some causes why maven does not use version 1.8 and use 1.5?

Comment: My pleasure. There are a few more details [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/), but it's not clear why 1.5 is the default.

Comment: OK. Thanks a lot anyway!